# ODP.NET, Managed reading LONG column results in ORA-01009

Tags: oracle, vb.net, odp.net, odp.net-managed

I'm trying to get the source of a view in my .net app.
To do this, I query `DBA_VIEWS`: it has a column `TEXT` with exactly what I need. The type is `LONG`.

If I do it using the Unmanaged driver, everything works as expected.
The same code with Managed driver results in `ORA-01009: missing mandatory parameter`.
Adding a transaction around the command *and* using breakpoint *and* "slow" steps *sometimes* results in the same code working.

ODP.NET version is 19, Oracle DB is 18c Express Edition. Strangely enough, the same code works just fine with Oracle Database 12c regardless of driver type.

Is there maybe some setting I need to change on the database or in code? I'm completely lost here.

Code I'm using for testing:

```vb
Imports System.Data.Common

Imports Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
'Imports Oracle.DataAccess

Module Views
    Function CreateCommand(Connection As DbConnection) As System.Data.Common.DbCommand
        Dim cmd As Data.Common.DbCommand = Connection.CreateCommand()
        With CType(cmd, Client.OracleCommand)
            .BindByName = True
            .FetchSize = &H100000 '1 Mb
            .InitialLONGFetchSize = -1 'the entire LONG or LONG RAW data is prefetched and stored in the fetch array.
            .InitialLOBFetchSize = -1 'the entire LOB data is prefetched and stored in the fetch array. 
        End With
        Return cmd
    End Function

    Sub query()
        Try
            Using DBConnection = New Client.OracleConnection("User ID=TESTUSER;Password=TESTPWD;Data Source=TESTDB;Pooling=True")
                DBConnection.Open()

                Using DBConnection.BeginTransaction()

                    Using cmdSQL = CType(CreateCommand(DBConnection), Client.OracleCommand)
                        cmdSQL.CommandText = "select TEXT from DBA_VIEWS where VIEW_NAME = :0"

                        Dim p = cmdSQL.CreateParameter()
                        p.ParameterName = "0"
                        p.Value = "TEST_VIEW"
                        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(p)

                        Dim sw = Stopwatch.StartNew

                        Using rdr = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader
                            rdr.FetchSize = 2 ^ 20
                            While rdr.Read
                                Dim row(rdr.FieldCount - 1) As Object
                                rdr.GetProviderSpecificValues(row)
                                Dim x = row(0)
                                Console.WriteLine($"{x.ToString.Length} bytes")
                            End While
                        End Using
                        Console.WriteLine($"{sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms")
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Not sure it will work but try this: `"begin select TEXT into :0 from DBA_VIEWS where VIEW_NAME = :1; end;"`. Add 2 parameters. Make sure that 1st `parameterDirection = output`, `oracleDbType = Long`, `size=1000000`. AND USE `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` . Then , if parameter retrieved, just use `cmd.Parametersp[0].Value.ToString()`

Comment: @T.S. this does indeed work, thanks!

Comment: Added answer. Even good to know for myself.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pity, Oracle deprecated `LONG` data type for ages but LONG data is still used many times for internal data.

You could write a function and then get the data by calling the function:

```
create or replace function GetViewText(v in varchar2) return clob is     
 ret CLOB;      
BEGIN

    FOR aRow IN (SELECT TEXT FROM DBA_VIEWS WHERE VIEW_NAME = v) LOOP
        ret := aRow.TEXT;
        -- or ret := TO_CLOB(aRow.TEXT);
    END LOOP;  
    RETURN ret;    
END;
```

Comment: yeah, pity isn't a word I would've used... Thanks, this is working, though since I'm forced to create a special function on .NET side either way I'll use the idea from the comment by @T.S. above (using return parameter with OracleDbType.Long).

Comment: AFAIU this won't work for Views using string literal form q'[ ... ]', will it?

Comment: that's a nice one. I've added OWNER to the WHERE statement and an EXIT statement to the loop to make clear we only want a single row, and am going to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an anonymous block with output parameter and a call to `ExecuteNonQuery`. Your command text will be

```vb
"begin select TEXT into :0 from DBA_VIEWS where VIEW_NAME = :1; end;"
```

Add 2 parameters. Make sure that

```vb
' Parameter #1 has
p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
p.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Long
p.Size = 1000000
```

And use command `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`. Then, when parameter is retrieved, just use its value

```vb
Dim txt As String = cmd.Parametersp[0].Value.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22043757) answer is to (ab)use `dbms_xmlgen.getxml`.
We can either use it to query a single view's code (as in my original question)

```sql
with input as (
 select
 :0 as VIEW_NAME
 from dual
)
SELECT
substr(
    text_xml,
    instr(text_xml, '<LONGCOL>') + length('<LONGCOL>'),
    instr(text_xml, '</LONGCOL>', -1) - (instr(text_xml, '<LONGCOL>') + length('<LONGCOL>'))
) as TEXT
from
(
    -- getxml can return malformed xml (which is good in this case)
    -- while getxmltype can not.
    select dbms_xmlgen.getxml(q'{
    SELECT TEXT as LONGCOL
    FROM SYS.DBA_VIEWS
    WHERE VIEW_NAME = '}' || input.VIEW_NAME || q'{'
}') as text_xml
from input
)
```

or create our own `DBA_VIEWS` version.

```sql
create or replace view APP_SCHEMA.DBA_VIEWS
as
select
    OWNER, VIEW_NAME, TEXT_LENGTH, 
    case
        when (TEXT_VC is not null and TEXT_LENGTH <= 4000)
            then to_clob(TEXT_VC)
        when TEXT is NULL
            then NULL
        else (
             SELECT
               substr(
                    text_xml,
                    instr(text_xml, '<LONGCOL>') + length('<LONGCOL>'),
                    --instr(text_xml, '</LONGCOL>', -1) - (instr(text_xml, '<LONGCOL>') + length('<LONGCOL>'))
                    TEXT_LENGTH
               ) as TEXT
              from
               (
                -- getxml can return malformed xml (which is good in this case)
                -- while getxmltype can not.
                select dbms_xmlgen.getxml(q'{
                SELECT TEXT as LONGCOL
                FROM SYS.DBA_VIEWS
                WHERE OWNER = '}' || OWNER || q'{'
                and VIEW_NAME = '}' || VIEW_NAME || q'{'
                }') as text_xml
                from dual
               )
        )
    end as TEXT,
    TEXT_VC, TYPE_TEXT_LENGTH, TYPE_TEXT, OID_TEXT_LENGTH, OID_TEXT, VIEW_TYPE_OWNER, VIEW_TYPE, SUPERVIEW_NAME, EDITIONING_VIEW, READ_ONLY, CONTAINER_DATA, BEQUEATH, ORIGIN_CON_ID, DEFAULT_COLLATION, CONTAINERS_DEFAULT, CONTAINER_MAP, EXTENDED_DATA_LINK, EXTENDED_DATA_LINK_MAP, HAS_SENSITIVE_COLUMN
from sys.dba_views
;
```